# How to use google cloud computing platform to perform a schedule task once a day

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a task that gathers some information from several web-sites and saves it to disk. I want this task to run on daily basis and automatically.

I took a little tour into google cloud platform, but couldn't understand how to fit this service to my needs.

I would really like it if someone could suggest some key-points/main guidelines on how it should be done.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to run any jobs which are time or scheduled based are done via CronJob of Linux. (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)

You can set up your scripts to be run at a specific time or interval and it should work. A checklist for you:

- Bash scripts of tasks you want to perform
- CronJobs that are schedules to run these scripts at specified time intervals

That should do it.